# Mixed content issue on Google Chrome only

Tags: php, html, forms, google-chrome, https

I'm getting mixed content issue when using Google Chrome only as

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over a
>   secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure
>   endpoint 'https:'. This endpoint should be made available over a
>   secure connection.

on the line of code

`<form id="zform" method="post" name="loginForm" action="//" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

There are no other points in the code which will create that problem. Also all resources are loaded via HTTPS.

Thoughts?

Comment: Does link in the `action` leads to  some `http://`?

Comment: Is the value of the action attribute actually `//`? If this is supposed to just point to the domain root, and use whatever protocol the page was loaded with - then just make it a single slash.

Comment: @freeek as the error shows above it leads to `https://`

Comment: @04FS Yeah - pointing to the domain root (reload itself). I had there `https://` instead `//`

Comment: @04FS You can post your suggestion to use singe `/` as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the value of the action attribute was actually `//`

If this is supposed to just point to the domain root, and use whatever protocol the page was loaded with - then just make it a single slash, `action="/"`

---

A protocol-relative URL is useful in certain situations, but mostly for when you are using absolute URLs to begin with, resp. are referring to a different domain. In this situation here, there doesn’t appear to be any real benefit over using just a relative URL path though.